# How to host an MS access database online?

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-platform

For my college project I am making a social media app which stores user data on an MS access database. However its no good of a social media app if the data cant be accessed online, so how would I go about doing it? I've looked into google cloud but it seems pretty confusing. I am used to MS access so is there a way of me making an access database and simply uploading it to some server I can then access from my c# code?

Comment: Not a wise idea to use a MS-Access in a concurrent scenario

Comment: However, you could still use access but not directly. You need to write some kind of REST Api on the server that hosts the database and then respond to your client requests

Comment: first, don't use Access, second, whatever you do use, add a webservice layer.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: "*a social media app which stores user data on an MS access database*" - that is your first problem. Just use Sql Server and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options I can think of that might work.

Option 1: Install Access in a cloud hosted VM and connect your application to it using ODBC (or other connection method).  The upside is this would simple to do.  The downsides are pretty major: 1) security is basically non-existent, and 2) Access is not scalable with higher concurrent requests (like a social media app might have).  This could be done on AWS or Azure.  Here's a Youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBivHfVuues) about how to do this.

Option 2: Use the 'Migration Assistant' to convert your Access project to Sql Server.  Then use Azure SQL (either pay-as-go or DTU's) to host the database.  Through the Azure portal you can get the connection string and ip address of the service and create firewall rules.  There's probably more learning involved with this but SQL Server is a really good database.  Here is a Youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bru9hZymPA) about how to do this.